# How we can use Window Splitter in C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have to split window in multiple parts in C++? Can anyone suggest me any API or give me some hints for Splitting Window ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of SDI:

```
class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CSplitterWnd m_wndSplitter; // add
}

BOOL CMainFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs, CCreateContext* pContext) 
{
    if(!m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2))
        return FALSE;

    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CXXXView), CSize(10,10), pContext);
    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CYYYView), CSize(10,10), pContext);
}
```